# Как объединить 2 блока row в один слайдер owl carousel?

Tags: css3, html5, bootstrap, owl-carousel

Имеется два блока .row, в них по 4 блока .vm-col-4. Необходимо чтобы при маленьком разрешении экрана эти два блока объединялись в один слайдер на owl carousel.
Использовать нужно только owl carousel.

Answer (score 0):

сделать в `html` дополнительно слайдер, поставить `display: none`. А потом на нужном разрешении `@media(){display: block}`. а изначальные 2 блока `row` спрятать

Answer (score 0):

Или использовать функцию определения типа устройства клиента. В wordpress - wp_is_mobile(). И в зависимости от ответа на php формировать ту или иную часть ответа.

Если у вас другая CMS, то можно посмотреть как устроена wp_is_mobile() например здесь: https://wp-kama.ru/function/wp_is_mobile

Ничего сложно - 6 строчек кода.

P.S. - если пойдёте таким путём, то в эмуляторе хрома надо обязательно перезагружать страницу, если начинаете смотреть код в десктопном варианте. Тогда всё отрабатывается нормально.